# Possible to create custom locale, such as fr_EN?

Tags: python, flask, python-babel, flask-babel

I am looking for a possibility to create a custom locale for my website. The website is available in several languages, including French. The French version of the website has particular content which is specific to France and not present in other languages. However, I need to translate this French version to English (therefore, having an English version of the French website – > fr_EN or en_FR).

Is this somehow possible in Flask Babel? Or how would I tackle this problem?